# Get ALL styles & add inline

Tags: jquery

Is there any way I can get all styles of an element as a variable and then add them to a style attribute?

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
var styles = $(this).css();
$('#element').attr('style', styles);
```

or

```
var styles = $(this).css();
$('#element').css({styles});
```

But it's not working.  I feel like there may be more to it and it's not as simple as I'm hoping.

Any help would be great!

Comment: might work `$('#element').attr("style", window.getComputedStyle(this).cssText)`

Comment: Hi @Jamiec I did see this but couldn't make sense of what it was telling me to do.

Comment: The accepted answer, and second-highest-voted answer show how to read all css styles from a given element and apply them to another element. Both answers have the code used in the actual answer.